# In angular2 routerLink on my view isnt working. How do I do an routerLink on my view and how do I import this?

Tags: angularjs, angular

In angular2 routerLink on my view isnt working. How do I do an routerLink on my view and how do I import this?

I'm using the new @angular/router.

**This is my code:**

```
import {Component, View} from '@angular/core';

import {Router, Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgIf} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'ForgotPassword',
  templateUrl: 'forgotpassword.html',
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgIf, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class ForgotPassword{}
```

**This is my html**

```
<a class="link" [routerLink]="['Login']">Login</a>
```

Comment: RouterLink doesnt seem to work from the lib @angular/router

Comment: You did add the route somewhere? It the route is on the main AppComponent you would need to do a /Login as the link.

Comment: All my routes are in the app.component

Comment: This is the console error I get when I click the link: Component 'ForgotPassword' does not have route configuration. But all my routes are in app.component. I can navigate to the Login route via the address bar fine. so the route exists. but cant seem to get that routerLink working in my markup?

Comment: try this <a class="link" [routerLink]="['/Login']">Login</a>

Comment: that didnt work. This is my app.component route for the login: 

  { path: '/login', component: Login, as: 'Login' }

Comment: seems like it should be a lower case /login then.

Comment: hmm that works now with lower case. Whats the point of as Login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

`<a class="link" [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>`