# How in angular2 can you get RouteParams for the new @Angular/router - doesnt seem to exist

Tags: angular

How in angular2 can you get RouteParams for the new @Angular/router - doesnt seem to exist

**This is my current code:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteParams} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'NewJob', 
  templateUrl: 'newJob.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Footer]
})

export class NewJob {
  router: Router;

  constructor(_router: Router, _params: RouteParams){   
       let slug = _params.get('slug');
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**only <= RC2**

You use the RouteSegment. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouteSegment-class.html

You would do use `getParam(param: string) : string` to get the parameter you need.

Comment: Can I import "RouteSegment" from @angular/router?

Comment: Cool I got it working, thanks. I did this: this.jobSlug = _params.getParam('slug');

Comment: Could you have a look at this similar question for me about RouterLink please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646160/in-angular2-routerlink-on-my-view-isnt-working-how-do-i-do-an-routerlink-on-my

Comment: @AngularM any chance you can do a quick plnker? Even the Angular.io documentation is "Not yet documented" for this class.

Answer (score 9):

`RouteSegment` no longer exists. You can use `ActivatedRoute`

**import:**

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
```

**constructor:**

```
constructor(private _routeParams: ActivatedRoute){}
```

**to get the params:**

```
this._routeParams.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params['id'];
    });
```